# Magento getting error to install modules

Tags: magento-1.7

I am new in magento. I have install many module in magento but always I am getting error 
Fatal error: Class some class like ('MN_Sendsms_Helper_Data') not found in /home/mart/public_html/prelaunch/app/Mage.php on line 546. after this error my admin panel and front end panel stop working. I want to know how to resolve this error because I want to implement modules but i am not able to install any module.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: You have installed a module MN_Sendsms but you have not uploaded the Data.php in Helper folder. If you have uploaded then the name varies with the one you mentioned in config.xml

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How to add Data.php file and where it will find?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this file exists:

```
/app/code/local/MN/Sendsms/Helper/Data.php
```

local or community in above path depends on where you have put the module

If not then it creates this class:

```
class MN_Sendsms_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

And make sure in the file

```
app/code/local/MN/Sendsms/etc/config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <sendsms>
                <class>Mn_Sendsms_Helper</class>
            </sendsms>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Don't Forget to refresh cache after all changes.

Comment: the data.php and config.xml both files are exist with same code. but i am still getting error
 Fatal error: Class 'MN_Sendsms_Helper_Data' not found in /home/mart/public_html/prelaunch/app/Mage.php on line 546.

How I refresh the cache my admin panel is not working?

Comment: i  think the issue is with my magento theme because  this happened with all modules. is this possible?

Comment: try by disabling theme.

Comment: Can you please give me a solution of this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802614/move-recently-viewed-products-box-magento) problem?

Comment: Where do you want to move the recently viewed box?

Comment: i want to display that box above footer.